# AMCL does not subscribe

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, amcl, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get robot pose estimation using gmapping in conjunction with amcl. Gmapping correctly builds the map using laser scans and I have tf, laser and map topic that publish messages. When I run amcl it does not publish the pose estimation and when I type rostopic info amcl_pose the node has no subscriber. How can I make the amcl node working?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44479/amcl-does-not-subscribe/) by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You either use gmapping or amcl. Both do particle-filtering based localization. While gmapping also builds a map, amcl requires an already built map on the [map server](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server). You cannot use amcl and gmapping at the same time.

After you built a map using gmapping and saved it to a file, you need to stop gmapping, start the map server to provide your map and run amcl.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2